# Django. How to aggregate amounts by payers group

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate

We develop an anti corruption analytical instrument that analyses government transactions and shows visual diagrams.

We have a table **"Transactions"** with column: **id, payer, recipient, amount and created_at.**

For example:

```
 1. "Kyiv CityHoll" | "Microsoft" | $130 | 2016.12.02
 2. "Odessa CityHoll" | "Microsoft" | $100 | 2016.12.02
 3. "Kyiv CityHoll" | "Google" | $1000 | 2016.12.02
 4. ...
```

How to:

**1.** Get sum of transactions by payer (for ex."Kyiv CityHoll" ) and make rating of TOP-payers by amount (the same payers must be grouped)?

**2.** Get sum of transactions by payer and resiver (for ex. all trasactions from "Kyiv CityHoll" to "Google")

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`annotate`  and `Sum`/`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet), you can do a lot of aggregations queries. Here's the queries for your examples:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
# 1. Get total of transactions per payer, ranked by total
Transactions.objects.values('payer').annotate(total=Sum('amount')) \
                    .order_by('-total')
# 2. Get total per payer/receiver, ranked by total
Transactions.objects.values('payer', 'receiver').annotate(total=Sum('amount')) \
                    .order_by('-total')
```

You will get a list of `dict` as result (since it can't match your model), so if `payer` and/or `receiver` is a ForeignKey, don't forget to get the proper attribute to retrieve the name (or do a separate query to get their full object)

Comment: How can I get the sum of the current month if my model has a datetime.now field?